# Relative Paths in own sdf element

Tags: gazebo-plugin, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

i am writing a plugin, which needs to load a csv file from a relative path with an own sdf-xml element file::myfile. Is there any gazebo-header, where methods are provided to resolve a file://myfile to the gazebo resource path?

Bbest regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12095/relative-paths-in-own-sdf-element/) by [Illuminatur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1512/illuminatur/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can try using SDF's [findFile](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/src/da854876f89fdd78d8e85197722464a4313897d4/include/sdf/SDFImpl.hh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#SDFImpl.hh-51) function.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0